# Why is AudioOutputUnitStart freezing my app in iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, core-audio, audiounit

I have an audio app which uses the RemoteIO AudioUnit. It works fine on iPhone, iPad, and any flavor of the simulator on 3.2, but when it hits AudioOutputUnitStart (), it freezes. I get the message "AddRunningClient starting device on non-zero client count" in the console, which I'm not sure how to resolve. I stop the unit and dispose of the AudioComponent every time the app closes. The app works fine the first time I run after restarting everything, but freezes every time after that. What's strange is there are no error messages - just an unresponsive interface and a frozen line of code.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Might be a bug in iOS 4. Did  you file a Radar with Apple?

Comment: The console message and the freezing may not not be related. I get the AddRunningClient message (only in iOS 4) as well and, per an Apple Engineer's feedback, the message is harmless and most likely due to having multiple players started at the same time.

Comment: That's very good to know - I'll keep looking. Haven't filed a bug report yet because I'm still not sure what's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart OSX makes it go away...